# CSS: Image pokes out of Bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following:

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">{{ article.headline }}</h2>
            <br/><h2 class="panel-title">{{ article.date|date:"l jS F Y" }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          {% if article.image %}
            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.image }}" class="article-image pull-right img-responsive col-md-· col-sm-6 col-xs-12" alt="{{ article.headline }}" />
          {% endif %}
          {{ article.text|safe }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And the image currently sticks out the bottom of the panel and makes it looks ever so odd.

The css for article image is simply:

```
.article-image {padding: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;}
@media(min-width: 768px){.article-image {margin-left: 20px;}}
```

Can anyone help understand why the image does not fit snugly within the panel?

Many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put your panel content inside a `div class="panel-body"` and give the image dimensions. Something like this

```
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">{{ article.headline }}</h2>
            <br/><h2 class="panel-title">{{ article.date|date:"l jS F Y" }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          {% if article.image %}
            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.image }}" class="article-image pull-right img-responsive col-md-· col-sm-6 col-xs-12" alt="{{ article.headline }}" />
          {% endif %}
          {{ article.text|safe }}
         </div>
        <div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

CSS

```
.article-image {
    padding: 0; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 50px; //whatever you want
    height: 50px; //whatever you want
}
@media(min-width: 768px){
    .article-image {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that :) doing family bits so will test it this evening. Just out of interest, will fixing the image width and height prevent it from being responsive ?

Comment: Maybe yes, but you can do a @media query and give it different size in base of min or max - width. Hope this helps.